# Rspec interprets empty array as lack of parameter with Grape

Tags: arrays, ruby, rspec, ruby-grape

I have a Ruby (non-Rails) app that uses Grape to expose API endpoints. One of the endpoints requires a parameter that is an array of values, but accepts an empty array as well:

```
requires :user_ids, type: Array, allow_blank: true
```

This all works fine when testing the endpoint manually using Curl or Postman - and empty array is properly interpreted as parameter `user_ids: []`. However, rspec seems to omit this whole parameter when its value is an empty array (non-empty array works perfectly of course):

```
let(:params) { { user_ids: [] } }
let(:route) { post "api/users/remove", params }
```

In this case, params that actually get passed equal `{}` and Grape's `requires` guard kicks in, not allowing the endpoint to execute anything.

Not sure if it's a bug or a feature and how to force rspec to pass this empty array as a parameter (behaves like this with both rspec 3.4 and 3.6).

Comment: Try using `params.to_json` and set header 'CONTENT_TYPE' to 'application/json'

Comment: https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/issues/723

Comment: @BartoszBonisławski yup, setting everything explicit in the test solved the problem. Please make it an answer and I will mark it as best one ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `params.to_json` and set header 'CONTENT_TYPE' to 'application/json'

Comment: Hi, this worked for me. For a different issue. I had an undocumented array in an api endpoint. Sending an empty array without calling `to_json` on the params made the array on the other side: `[""]` which was very weird. Why does adding these two things make this work?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone wondering:

1. This is caused by the [`Rack::Test` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632058/535406) and not `RSpec`.
2. There is a shortcut for the Bartosz's answer:

```rb
post 'api/users/remove', params: params, as: :json
```