# RSpec request spec post an empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, http-post, rspec-rails

I am current developing an API endpoint in rails. I want to be sure the endpoint response with the correct error status if the data I need is invalid. I need an array of ids. One of the invalid values is an empty array.

#### Valid

```
{ vendor_district_ids: [2, 4, 5, 6]}
```

#### Invalid

```
{ vendor_district_ids: []}
```

#### Request Spec with RSpec

So I want to have a request spec to control my behaviour.

```ruby
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::PossibleAppointmentCountsController, type: :request do
  let(:api_auth_headers) do
    { 'Authorization' => 'Bearer this_is_a_test' }
  end

  describe 'POST /api/possible_appointments/counts' do
    subject(:post_request) do
      post api_my_controller_path,
        params: { vendor_district_ids: [] },
        headers: api_auth_headers
    end

    before { post_request }

    it { expect(response.status).to eq 400 }
  end
end
```

As you can see I use an empty array in my param inside the `subject` block.

#### Value inside the controller

In my controller I am fetching the data with

```
params.require(:vendor_district_ids)
```

and the value is the following

```ruby
<ActionController::Parameters {"vendor_district_ids"=>[""], "controller"=>"api/my_controller", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

The value of `vendor_district_ids` is an array with an empty string. I do not have the same value when I make a post with `postman`.

#### Value with postman

If I post

```
{ "vendor_district_ids": [] }
```

the controller will receive

```ruby
<ActionController::Parameters {"vendor_district_ids"=>[], "controller"=>"api/my_controller", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

And here is the array empty.

#### Question

Am I doing something wrong inside the request spec or is this a bug from `RSpec`?

Comment: Is there's a difference between postman headers and the headers in the test? especially looking for `Content-Type`

Comment: Just a thought, because I've just had a similar issue. What happens if you do this `params: { "vendor_district_ids" => [] }`

Comment: Have a look at my answer, I think I have concluded the reason as to why we recieve this inconsistency between Postman and RSPEC, as well as a solution to avoid modifying your controllers to account for empty arrays.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer!

#### Problem

The problem is found inside Rack's `query_parser` not actually inside rack-test as the previous answer indicates.

The actual translation of `"paramName[]="` into `{"paramName":[""]}` happens in Rack's [query_parser](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/8f71f53c3140cee2070188d839561715d8f3b064/lib/rack/query_parser.rb#L64).

An example of the problem:

```rb
post '/posts', { ids: [] }
{"ids"=>[""]} # By default, Rack::Test will use HTTP form encoding, as per docs: https://github.com/rack/rack-test/blob/master/README.md#examples
```

#### Solution

Convert your params into JSON, by requiring the JSON gem into your application using `'require 'json'` and appending your param hash with `.to_json`.

And specifying in your RSPEC request that the content-type of this request is JSON.

An example by modifying the example above:

```rb
post '/posts', { ids: [] }.to_json, { "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json" }
{"ids"=>[]} # explicitly sending JSON will work nicely
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me hours of hair-pulling.

Answer (score 4):

For everyone wondering — there's a shortcut solution:

```rb
post '/posts', params: { ids: [] }, as: :json
```

Answer (score 3):

That is actually caused by `rack-test >= 0.7.0` [1].

It converts empty arrays to `param[]=` which is later decoded as `['']`.

If you try running the same code with e.g. `rack-test 0.6.3` you will see that `vendor_district_ids` isn't added to the query at all:

```
# rack-test 0.6.3
Rack::Test::Utils.build_nested_query('a' => [])
# => ""

# rack-test >= 0.7.0
Rack::Test::Utils.build_nested_query('a' => [])
# => "a[]="

Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query('a[]=')
# => {"a"=>[""]}
```

[1] https://github.com/rack-test/rack-test/commit/ece681de8ffee9d0caff30e9b93f882cc58f14cb

Answer (score 0):

I could not send it as json as in my case as i was sending also sending files as multipart form.. my workaround was to put an empty string inside the array..

```
post '/posts', params: { ids: [""] }
```